# How to chain axios HTTP requests

Tags: javascript, http, server, async-await, axios

I have 2 async await functions - one of them makes axios post request and another one - axios get request.

How could I chain them so that I would wait until the post operation is done and after it is completed, fetch new and updated objects?

```
const expensesListToDB = async () => {
    await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist', 
    {
        expenseTitle: Expense,
        expenseAmount: Amount
    });
}

const expensesListFromDB = async () => {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
    .then(
    response => setExpenseAndAmountList(response.data && response.data.length > 0 ? response.data : []));
}

expensesListToDB();
expensesListFromDB();
```

Thanks!

Comment: return promise from `expensesListToDB` and in `.then` you can run the function `expensesListFromDB`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can put expensesListFromDB() in the 'then' method of the Axios.

```
const expensesListToDB = async () => {
    await axios.post('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist', 
    {
        expenseTitle: Expense,
        expenseAmount: Amount
    }).then(
    response => expensesListFromDB()); }

const expensesListFromDB = async () => {
    await axios.get('http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist')
    .then(
    response => setExpenseAndAmountList(response.data && response.data.length > 0 ? response.data : [])); }

expensesListToDB();
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the API is in your control, the answers given by others are viable i would imagine a system where you return the new document in the response of the post request and just use it from their making it one single request

To have error handling and fault tolerance you could design your API response  like this

```
{ "statusCode":"200",
  "event":"doc_added_successfully",
  "newDocs":{
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return `Promise` from `expensesListToDB` and in the `.then` block you can run the function `expensesListFromDB`

> Once an HTTP POST request is made, Axios returns a promise that is either fulfilled or rejected, depending on the response from the backend service.

```
const expensesListToDB = () => {
  return axios.post("http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist", {
    expenseTitle: Expense,
    expenseAmount: Amount,
  });
};

const expensesListFromDB = async () => {
  await axios
    .get("http://localhost:4000/app/expenseslist")
    .then((response) =>
      setExpenseAndAmountList(
        response.data && response.data.length > 0 ? response.data : []
      )
    );
};

expensesListToDB().then((data) => {
  expensesListFromDB();
});
```